# Multiply char array of integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, multiplication

Can some one help me multiply this example with for loops in C ?
well,

I have char array as example

```
 x[]={ '0','3','0','8','9','6','4','3','8','4','0','0','7' };

* 765432,765432
```

and I need mulitply elements as:

```
ZZZ=(0*7)+(3*6)+(0*5)+(8*4)+(9*3)+(6*2)+(4*7)+(3*6)+(8*5)+(4*4)+(0*3)+(0*2)=
 0 +18 + 0 +32 +27 +12 +28 +18 +40 +16 +0 +0 = 191
```

What do you think:

I tried :

```
int mnozi = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    //mnozi = (int)p[i]-48; 
    for (int j = 7; j > 1; j--) 
        mnozi = ((int)p[i] - 48) *j;
        printf("\n%d", mnozi);

        ZZZ = ZZZ + mnozi;
    }
```

and there are some strange outputs!

Comment: Would you mind telling us how to determine which element should be multiplied in each term?

Comment: `p` in the code means `x`, right? What are `i` and `ZZZ`?

Comment: You should use clearer `'0'` instead of the magic number `48`.

Comment: You only want the first 12 numbers, with the final 7 ignored?

Comment: @MikeCAT His array is (0, 3,0, 8,4,..)  etc. and he is trying to multiply each element of that array with each element of (7,6,5,43...) etc and then sum the results.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to multiply the array by your descending `7-2` pattern repeated twice. One is a simple use of a pointer to walk down `x` through two iterations of the pattern. It can be coded a number of ways, another would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char x[]={ '0','3','0','8','9','6','4','3','8','4','0','0','7' }, *p = x;
    int i = 7, r = 0, z = 0;

    for (; *p && p < x + sizeof x; p++) {
        printf (" %d * %d = %d\n", *p - '0', i, (*p - '0') * i);
        z += (*p - '0') * i--;
        if (i < 2) { i = 7; if (++r > 1) break; }
    }

    printf ("\n z : %d\n\n", z);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/multcharray

 0 * 7 = 0
 3 * 6 = 18
 0 * 5 = 0
 8 * 4 = 32
 9 * 3 = 27
 6 * 2 = 12
 4 * 7 = 28
 3 * 6 = 18
 8 * 5 = 40
 4 * 4 = 16
 0 * 3 = 0
 0 * 2 = 0

 z : 191
```

A slight variation limiting the iterations by limiting the characters in `x` the multiplication is applied to could be:

```
    char x[]={ '0','3','0','8','9','6','4','3','8','4','0','0','7' }, *p = x;
    int i = 7, z = 0;

    for (; *p && p < x + sizeof x - 1; p++) {
        z += (*p - '0') * i;
        printf (" %d * %d = %d\n", *p - '0', i, (*p - '0') * i);
        if (--i < 2) i = 7;
    }

    printf ("\n z : %d\n\n", z);
```

The variations are endless. Look over all the answers and let us know if yo have any questions.

Comment: Minor: Perhaps `x + sizeof x` should  be  `x + sizeof x/sizeof x[0]`.  Present code _works_ because `sizeof x[0] == 1`.  For maintenance, `x` could change type.  If maintenance is not important, then why not use `p < x + 13`?

Comment: Eye sharp as ever. Yes were the array not type `char` we would need to number of elements. In this case since the intent was to step one byte at a time over the `short` it was omitted. `sizeof x` was chosen to prevent including magic numbers, but point well taken on the prospect of a change in type.

Answer (score 2):

Using nested loop seems wrong. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char x[]={ '0','3','0','8','9','6','4','3','8','4','0','0','7' };
    char *p = x;
    int i, ZZZ;

    int mnozi = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        //mnozi = (int)p[i]-48; 
        int j = 7 - i % 6;
        mnozi = ((int)p[i] - '0') *j;
        printf("\n%d", mnozi);
        printf(" : i = %d, p[i] = '%c', i %% 6 = %d, j = %d", i, p[i], i % 6, j); /* to making what is happening clearer */

        ZZZ = ZZZ + mnozi;
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", ZZZ);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 : i = 0, p[i] = '0', i % 6 = 0, j = 7
18 : i = 1, p[i] = '3', i % 6 = 1, j = 6
0 : i = 2, p[i] = '0', i % 6 = 2, j = 5
32 : i = 3, p[i] = '8', i % 6 = 3, j = 4
27 : i = 4, p[i] = '9', i % 6 = 4, j = 3
12 : i = 5, p[i] = '6', i % 6 = 5, j = 2
28 : i = 6, p[i] = '4', i % 6 = 0, j = 7
18 : i = 7, p[i] = '3', i % 6 = 1, j = 6
40 : i = 8, p[i] = '8', i % 6 = 2, j = 5
16 : i = 9, p[i] = '4', i % 6 = 3, j = 4
0 : i = 10, p[i] = '0', i % 6 = 4, j = 3
0 : i = 11, p[i] = '0', i % 6 = 5, j = 2
191
```

Comment: Curious: Why the cast in `((int)p[i] - '0')`?  `(p[i] - '0')` causes `p[i]` to be cast to typically  `int`.  Perhaps following OP's style?